# How to Display Menu Icons after clicking the More item in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

if I have an Options menu in Android that has more than 6 items, Android adds a More item that shows the other hidden items, AS text!

But I want the More button to display the extra items both in their text AND icon, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible, unless you code that by your self. And by "code" I mean you create a custom menu.

Comment: Drats! Do you know of any similar custom implementation?